# Is Jiggly Jiggly Heaven a reference to an existing series?

Tags: shirobako

Jiggly Jiggly Heaven is the series that the animation team in Shirobako worked on previously that was notorious for a disastrous episode. Specifically, the ninth episode.

[image]

It became an internet sensation (in the Shirobako universe), but for all the wrong reasons.

[image]

I know the show likes to throw in references to other production studios and works - Is there any particular work that is being referenced here?

Comment: Perhaps [*Girls und Panzer*](https://infinitemirai.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/girls-und-panzer-an-unexpected-intermission-and-future-directions/)? There were a lot of significant production issues and they same they director (Mizushima Tsutomu)...

Comment: It looks like that had significant delays - but the animation wasn't a problem

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure.... [A single production issue](http://girls-und-panzer.at.webry.info/201212/article_15.html) in the twelve episode series cascaded into production hell:  two recap episodes, a three month delay in broadcasting the last two episodes, and delays for Blu-ray and OVA releases.